# mkdir in Java to create new folder

Tags: java, mkdir

I'm using netbeans 8.

In my project folder I manually created a folder called "Storage" and 
now I'm trying to create within it a new folder programmatically.
but I don't see the new folder.

this is what I did:

```
 File folder = new File("../Storage/Test");
 folder.mkdir();
```

after the project was running I entered to the Storage folder to see if "Test" folder
was created, and nothing.. it was empty

Comment: Show us how you created your `Storage` folder.

Comment: @Sparrow:- He created it manually....`I manually created a folder called "Storage"`

Comment: Then where did he created it this folder@R.T. And by the way this question is not appropriate for this forum

Comment: I think netbeans uses the project folder as the current directory, not the `bin` folder. Try removing the `../` from your path.

Comment: @Sparrow `In my project folder I manually created a folder called "Storage"` :3

Comment: Here you get your answer by user3922563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File("../Storage/Test");
```

this file correspond to the following structure if using netbeans.

--`Anyworkingdirectory` // by default in netbeans 'my document' of your account
    |
    |--`myproject` ... // your project
    |
    |--`Storage`
        |
        |--`Test`

So check your Storage folder if it is in correct place or not. Because there is nothing wrong in your code. The problem is where you created that `Storage` directory.

Comment: Storage is in my project folder.  if you ask how I created the storage folder, so in netbeans solution i pressed right click on my project, then new folder.. so the Storage folder is placed in the project folder.

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:

```
new File("Storage/Test").mkdirs();
```

The [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

Comment: The first `/` in your path looks like an absolute path, I think OP wants relative to his/hers project folder.

Comment: @kajacx:- I am not sure about that as OP has not mentioned it! Do you think I should remove that?

Comment: `In my project folder I manually created a folder called "Storage" and now I'm trying to ...`. And yes, removing should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try with this too...

```
File currentPath = new File("Images");
currentPath.mkdir();
File file = new File(currentPath.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "Foreground" + File.separator
                    + "MyFile");
file.mkdirs();
```

Specially use the File.separator